# Make an image come out of a div with background-image

Tags: html, css

I need some help, I need to code this image:

[image: Image that needs to be coded]

This is what I have so far:
[image]

I tried adding a margin-top, padding-top, tried all combinations of position relative and absolute, I just need some ideias on how to do it.

This is how my code is structured:

```
<div class="background-oficina">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
      <img class="logo" src="logo.png" alt="Oficina de Redação">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the css for the two classes that I'm using:

```
.background-oficina {
  background: #fff url("bg-texture.png");
}

.logo {
  padding-top: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Whats the problem?

Comment: `position: absolute` should work, but you will have to declare an explicit height for the parent because the child (logo) is taken out of the flow, causing the parent's dimensions to collapse. Can you at least create an MCVE for your issue? I can see that you are using bootstrap.

Comment: A white border-bottom for the container element, a negative margin-bottom of the same width for the image ... https://jsfiddle.net/gnvzaaho/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an additional absolutely positioned element to which you assign the repeated background pattern and which you put behind the original element by using `z-index: -1`:

```css
html, body {
margin: 0;
}
.background-oficina {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.bg-container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  top;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;  /* or whatever height is desired */
  background: url("http://placehold.it/20x15/cff");
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.logo {
  padding-top: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-oficina">
  <div class="bg-container"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
      <img class="logo" src="http://placehold.it/200x150/fb7" alt="Oficina de Redação">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your trying this, you can set default `height and width to parent div` that consist of that `logo` then using `position:absolute` you can push that out of parent div, but don't add `overflow:hidden` to `parent div` or else it hides your image or element that you are trying to push outside parent div as hidden.

```css
.background-oficina {
  background: #fff url("https://via.placeholder.com/800x100/000") no-repeat;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative; /*Add this*/
}

.logo {
  padding-top: 50px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  position: absolute; /*Add this*/
  bottom: -20px; /*Add this*/
}
```

```html
<div class="background-oficina padding margin-bottom">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center margin-bottom">
      <img class="logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50/ff2" alt="Oficina de Redação">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```